# Wordpress: default-widgets.php

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress and how things work in it. I have a specific question regarding default-widgets.php. Is it being called by default when I install wordpress? if so in what page?

Also, I regarding line 1413 in the default-widgets.php, where is it first called as a user input?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The default widgets are loaded automatically by WordPress. You could find them in the backend of your website when you navigate to `Appearance` > `Widgets`. [Find more datails at the WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets#Existing_Widgets_in_Existing_Widget_Areas)

And for the other question, I think you're asking about the `WP_Nav_Menu_Widget` class. It is used in the *Custom Menu* widget.